# Xcode build using python subprocess

Tags: python, xcode, subprocess, python-3.4

I have a python script for xcode build. A part of it is shown below.

```
cmd = "xcodebuild -verbose -configuration Release -workspace".split()
cmd += [PROJECT_WORKSPACE_FOLE_NAME_PATH]
cmd += "-scheme".split()
cmd += [scheme]
cmd += "CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR =".split()
cmd += [APP_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY]
cmd += "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY =".split()
cmd += [DEVELOPER_ID]
cmd += "OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS = ".split()
cmd += [--keychain, TEAMCITY_KEYCHAIN_PATH]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

This gives me an error.

```
xcodebuild: error: invalid option '--keychain'
```

Please help me out.

**EDIT::Equivalent working bash script is given below**

```
  xcodebuild -verbose -configuration Release -workspace  "$PROJECT_WORKSPACE_FILENAME_PATH" -scheme "$SCHEME"    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="$APP_OUTPUT_DIR" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$DEVELOPER_ID" OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain $TEAMCITY_RUN_SCRIPT_LOCATION/$TEAMCITY_KEYCHAIN"
```

Comment: This doesn't see to have anything to do with Python. [`xcodebuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) doesn't have a `--keychain` option, so if you correctly pass a `--keychain` option, you're just going to get an error saying there is no such option. Why did you expect otherwise?

Comment: @abarnert: I even tried `cmd = "xcodebuild -verbose -configuration Release -workspace" + project_workspace_filename_path + "-scheme" + scheme + "CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR =" + app_output_directory + "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY =" + developer_id + 'OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS = ' + developer_id + -keychain + value` which gave me an error `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'dict'`

Comment: Well, yeah, you didn't quote `-keychain`, so you're calling the `-` operator on whatever value you happen to have in the variable `keychain`, which is unlikely to be what you want. But also, you didn't fix any of the problems mentioned in my answer, and you added new ones, so I'm not sure why you expected that to help anything.

Comment: @abarnert: The commands above were tried yesterday and not after reading your answer..I have added the equivalent working bash command in the question as you suggested

Comment: OK, the error is exactly what I said it probably was. I've updated my answer to explain more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem is that you're passing settings wrong. If you look at the [`xcodebuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) manpage, you can see that they're passed as a single argument `setting=value`. For example, in your (working) bash example, one of the arguments is:

```
OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain $TEAMCITY_RUN_SCRIPT_LOCATION/$TEAMCITY_KEYCHAIN"
```

But in your Python code, you're passing that as four separate arguments: `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS`, `=`, `--keychain`, and the value of `TEAMCITY_KEYCHAIN_PATH`.

That's not the same thing. Apparently `xcodebuild` is interpreting `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS`, `=`, and the path as something valid (but probably not something you want), but it's treating `--keychain` as a flag that it doesn't know anything about, and that's what you get the error for.

The solution is to build a single argument, just like you did in `bash`. Instead of this:

```
cmd += "OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS = ".split()
cmd += [--keychain, TEAMCITY_KEYCHAIN_PATH]
```

Do this:

```
cmd += ["OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS=--keychain " + TEAMCITY_KEYCHAIN_PATH]
```

But you've made the same mistake on every other setting. And I wouldn't be surprised if there were other arguments you're passing wrong. So just fixing this one error won't make everything magically work; you have to fix all of them.

Comment: When I tried `-keychain` I got `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'dict'`..so i just tried `--keychain` because it worked for me as a bash script

Comment: @NevinRaj: If you have a bash script that works—or, again, even if you just have a command line that you can manually type yourself in the terminal that works—post that in your question, and you can work out how to get there in Python, instead of just randomly changing things in your Python script hoping that eventually something will magically work.

Comment: I was exactly trying to do the same..But I am not so good in coding and also I am beginner to python..thats the problem..sorry for wasting your time